# how save object to arraylist like C# in php

Tags: php

how save object to arraylist like C# in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no distinction between object arrays and ArrayLists in PHP due to PHP's dynamic typing.

Edit

Just in case this is what you meant:

```
$myArray[] = $obj;
```

Will append the object $obj onto the array $myArray.

Answer (score -1):

How to insert an item into an array:
http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/08/02/php-insert-into-an-array-at-a-specific-position/